# Capture ip address from Spring controller to JSP

Tags: java, jsp

My spring app has a controller like this: `https://my.app.com/project1/token`.  When a user clicks this link, I redirect them to a jsp in my WEB-INF folder to collect some client-side data from a jsp (info like langauge, local, time, etc).  I want to capture the IP address as well, but I'm not able to get any data from my controller.  This is the code I have so far:

```
servletRequest.setAttribute("ip", servletRequest.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR"));
servletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(DEVICE_INFO).forward(servletRequest, servletResponse);
```

And in my JSP I have:

```
console.log("IP address is - ${ip}");
```

But it is coming up empty.  Is there a better solution for this? If I just use `servletRequest.setAttribute("ip", servletRequest.getRemoteHost());` I get the ip of the jsp host (which is docker at the moment, I want to get the ip address of the user who clicked the link).

Answer (score 0):

The `X-FORWARDED-FOR` is only set if there is a proxy in the middle, which is setting that header. If you have no proxy, or the proxy is not setting that header, you will not get anything there.

Did you try something like this?

```
  String remoteAddr = servletRequest.getHeader("X-FORWARDED-FOR");
  if (remoteAddr == null || remoteAddr.equals("")) {
      remoteAddr = servletRequest.getRemoteAddr();
  }
```

It works on normal setups, not sure what your docker setup is doing.

Comment: It does get an IP, but it's the IP of my localhost (docker in this case), not the client, so its something like 172.17... My app needs to validate that the request is actually coming from the user, so we verify it over the ip address.  I know there is a way in jsps using webrtc, but I read it isn't as secure as it should be.  I was hoping to get a solution in my controller

Comment: Is the request being done by another application? Do you have some node.js or something in front of your Spring Boot application?

Comment: So my app works like this: User a clicks on link `https://my.app.com/project/token?tokenVal=123`. I have that endpoint mapped to a Spring controller.  This controller takes the token value, and forwards the request to a jsp in my WEB-INF folder to use that token to collect client info.  I need the JSP to be able to get the client's IP who clicked the link, right now it's getting localhost which is where my app is running

Comment: Can you put the code I gave you in the first controller that is hit by the user? The one that decodes the token? To see if the IP of the user is reaching that point first.